# Make a Menu div spread in the middle and work in smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website for a client, and one of my last problems which I can't solve is a menu issue. I believe this might be helpful for other people.

The menu has three `div`s inside it (the parent is a `div`) .
Here is the code, a bit shortened:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><img src='logo.png' /></div>
    <div id='languageSELECT'>LANGUAGE SELECT</div>
    <div id="Menu">
        <ul id="menu_noya">
            <li class="head_item">
                <a href="index.php?page=Women">{$language["MenuWomen"]}</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><span style='color:#352618;font-family:tahoma;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;'>{$language["InMenuWomen"]}</span></li>
                    <li><a href='index.php?page=Women'><img src='/styles/Images/women1.jpeg' style='height:170px;width:120px;' /></a></li>
                    <li><a href='index.php?page=Women'><img src='/styles/Images/women2.jpeg' style='height:170px;width:120px;' /></a></li>
                    <li><a href='index.php?page=Women'><img src='/styles/Images/women3.jpeg' style='height:170px;width:120px;' /></a></li>
                    <li><a href='index.php?page=Women'><img src='/styles/Images/women4.jpeg' style='height:170px;width:120px;' /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="head_item">
                { like this 5 more times } ...
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#LanguageSelect
{
    float:right;
    width:150px;
    margin-top:65px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

#menu_noya, #menu_noya ul {
    list-style: none;
    z-index:1;
}

#menu_noya, #menu_noya * { 
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

#menu_noya li.head_item {
    float:left;
    width:142px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu_noya li.head_item a {
    display: block;
    color:#62E1E3;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:lighter;
}

li.head_item ul { 
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
}

li.head_item:hover ul {
    margin-right:50px; 
    position:absolute;
    display: block; 
    width:150px;
    background-color:#ececec;
    border-right:8px solid #352618;
}

#header {
    background-color:#352618;
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#logo
{
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:80px;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-left:15px;
}

#Menu {
    font-size:16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:65px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

---

The problems are:

- On small laptops (13-inch or 11-inch) with smaller resolutions, the middle menu gets out of the header `div`, so it's not in the header and ends up below it. This is the same on the iPad and iPhone.
- On some PCs and laptops, the menu isn't in the middle of the page, because the `logo` and `languageSELECT` elements need to be the same width. The menu is in the middle between the logo and the language select, but not in the middle of the page.

I've tried to do `@media` queries, but it's very "general" and works on some devices but not others. That works for a specific device, which I can do, but what about the others?

The main thing I want here is to make the menu 100% of the width it's given. Let's assume my resolution is 1024px; if I have 250px for the logo and 150px for the language select, then there are 624px left. I want the menu to spread 100% of that 624px.

One little additional question: smaller text looks very blurry on my website, like it's not anti-aliased. Is there a good font that looks like Times New Roman that works for small font sizes?

Comment: Use a media query for a specific max-width, so you get all devices under a general resolution. See the [resolution media queries](http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/#). `@media screen and (max-width: 1028px) {}`for instance.

Comment: I'l try, though another problem is the menu , it should be in the middle of the SCREEN , not the header , that's a problem , it sometimes too much left or right instead of center.

Comment: That's the part you should have looked for on SO. `position:fixed;z-index: 100;  top:50%;  left:50%;  margin:-100px 0 0 -100px;  width:200px;  height:200px;  ` Set the margins as the half the width of your element, and negative.

Comment: I did put it on : #menu_noya li.head_item and it didn't work..

Comment: Apply it to the `#menu` element. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/gJ2Gy/

Comment: Sorry , I did apply it to the #menu , and it doesn't work , it's like going out of the header to the right side of the screen .. I tryed to modify things there , still clueless, like in the jsfiddle example .

Comment: You might want to clarify your needs. I thought you wanted the menu to be centered in the **screen** (which is was I did in the JSFiddle). If you only want to menu to be in the center of your `header` element, then just apply `margin:0 auto;` to the `#menu` element.

Comment: No no , I want it to be in the middle of the screen , Iv'e applied what you did on JSFIDDLE and it didn't work.

Comment: [It seems quite in the center to me.](http://i.imgur.com/pjCrSgE.jpg) And it is working in Firefox, IE9-10-11dev and latest Chrome release from what I tested here

Comment: Look , the {$language} is in the middle of the screen , I want it in the middle of the screen , in the header, I mean horizonaly ( x only ) not y , Sorry if you missunderstood me , I meant I want in the middle of the Header , but if u put margin:0 auto; as i said on top ,it's in the middle between the logo and the languageselect, and it should be in the middle of the screen ( x )

Comment: Because if the menu will use margin:0 auto; it will be in the middle like this: [LOGO]   [menu]  [L] , and the L and LOGO isn't in the same width, so it won't be in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Adding some `margin-left` or `padding-left` to the L wouldn't do the job? Same thing for logo (but with `margin-right` et `padding-right`).

Comment: How can I calculate it in order them to have the same width using padding and margin? and I also need to calculate it into the media queries also , is there a way? Because there are many different resulutions and it is different in every os or screen.

Comment: I also need which is the most important is to make the menu 100% on it's width it got, How can I do it?
If the header is 1024 px , the logo is 250 and the language is 150 , I want the 624 pixels left, the menu [text] [text] to be spead 100% on the middle